# Check if a user can run the RECONFIGURE statement

Tags: sql-server, t-sql, permissions

I'm using SQL Server Express on AWS and, when trying to change the `MAXDOP` via a T-SQL query, I got an error stating

> Database Error: [Microsoft][SQL Server Native Client 11.0][SQL
> Server]User does not have permission to perform this action. (37000:
> 15,247) ... You do not have permission to run the RECONFIGURE
> statement (37000: 5,812).

I suppose this can also happen on SQL Server instances that are not on AWS, it seems to be a user permission problem.

Is there a way to **programmatically check if** a user **can** (or cannot) run the `RECONFIGURE` statement, preferably running a T-SQL query on SQL Server >= 2014?

Comment: Per the [Permissions](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reconfigure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) section of the documentation, the **`LOGIN`** (not `USER`) requires the ALTER SETTINGS permission. The `sysadmin` and `serveradmin` server roles have this permission implicitly, however, you can check if a specific `LOGIN` or server role has it assigned by reviewing the `sys.server_permissions` table.

Comment: I only know the username and password that the person running my script inputs to connect to a SQL Server they specify. Is that username sufficient?

Comment: If the account you have doesn't have the permissions you need, then you can't use that account to elevate your permissions, no.

Comment: I need *to programmatically check if a user* has the permission needed to run that statement. I know the "user name", I don't know what you mean by "login".

Comment: A `LOGIN` is a server level principle you use to connect to the instance, @Agostino .

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The [`RECONFIGURE` statement](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/language-elements/reconfigure-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15#permissions) requires the server-level `ALTER SETTINGS` permission. The [`fn_my_permissions` TVF](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/system-functions/sys-fn-my-permissions-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15) can be used programmatically to check if the current user has the permission:

```
IF NOT EXISTS(
    SELECT 1
    FROM fn_my_permissions(NULL, 'server')
    WHERE permission_name = N'ALTER SETTINGS'
    )
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Current user does not have ALTER SETTINGS permission needed for RECONFIGURE statement';
END;
```

Alternatively per the comment by @lptr, one can use the [HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME scalar function](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/functions/has-perms-by-name-transact-sql?view=sql-server-ver15):

```
IF HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(NULL, NULL, 'ALTER SETTINGS') = 0
BEGIN
    PRINT N'Current user does not have ALTER SETTINGS permission needed for RECONFIGURE statement';
END;
```

Comment: or `HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'ALTER SETTINGS')  `

Comment: I'll upvote Dan's solution for its completeness, but `SELECT HAS_PERMS_BY_NAME(null, null, 'ALTER SETTINGS')` seems to be the one that fits my case best. @lptr If you post that as an answer, I'll accept it.

Comment: @Agostino .. the answer is complete

Comment: @lptr As you prefer. I upvoted your comment. If you found my question clear and worth answering, please upvote.